# What Type is Auth.auth()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to DRY up my app by creating a Firebase DataService but I don't know what type to cast for Auth.auth(). I looked at the Source Code Definition but it is in Objective C which I do not understand. Is extracting Auth.auth() even possible?

Here is what I have:

```
let FB_AUTH = Auth.auth()
let DB_BASE = Database.database().reference()
let FB_STORAGE = Storage.storage().reference()

class FBData {
    static let fbi = FBData()

    //MARK: PROPERTIES
    private var _FB_AUTH = FB_AUTH
    private var _REF_BASE = DB_BASE
    private var _STORAGE_BASE = FB_STORAGE
    private var _REF_USERS = DB_BASE.child("users")

    //MARK: PRIVATE GETTERS
    var FB_AUTH: NSObject {
        return _FB_AUTH
    }

    var REF_BASE: DatabaseReference {
        return _REF_BASE
    }

    var STORAGE_BASE: StorageReference
    {
        return _STORAGE_BASE
    }

    var REF_USERS: DatabaseReference {
        return _REF_USERS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the source, as you said, I see:

```
+ (FIRAuth *)auth NS_SWIFT_NAME(auth());
```

`(FIRAuth *)` is the return type.  So `Auth.auth()` is of type `FIRAuth` (`Auth` in Swift) which inherits from `NSObject`

```
NS_SWIFT_NAME(Auth)
@interface FIRAuth : NSObject
```

Comment: thanks ... I don't think I can extract Authentication because when I changed it to FIRAuth, I got "'FIRAuth' has been renamed to 'Auth'" and when I use the return type of "Auth", I get "Cannot use instance member 'FB_AUTH' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: I updated my answer to show that `FIRAuth` is just `Auth` in Swift.  Your initialization problem is another issue altogether.  Can you do something like `private var _FB_AUTH = Auth.auth()`?